# Is it possible to replace C++ standard library with C standard library when linking C++ programs?

Tags: c++, c, linker, g++

I have two related questions, one more theoretical for curiosity and another one asking for a possible use case.

(1) Would it be possible to compile a C++ program (using e.g., g++) but link the program with the C standard library (e.g., libc) instead of the C++ standard library (e.g., libstdc++) ? I know the C++ standard library contains the C standard library, but I am asking for a way to keep *only* the C library. I know it is possible to remove the standard library with the `-nostdlib` flag, but I would like to remove only the "C++ part" of the standard library and keep the "C part".

(2) From what I have heard, one reason why some people still use C instead of C++ is when the target system has low memory (e.g., an embedded system) where the C++ stdlib would be too big for the available memory. In this case, would replacing the C++ stdlib with the C stdlib solves the issue and allows these people to use C++ language features (namespace, more type safety, etc.) at no cost ? If it is possible, would there be downsides ? Why aren't today's C programmers doing this?

Comment: you will have to rewrite all .h files  to declare all functions as `extern "C"`

Comment: Poimt 2 is not relevant. Embedded system programmers know how to use C++ in low resources environments. There are more important problems - for example dynamic memory allocation (should be avoided, many standards ban it) which have to be sorted out when using C++ for uC programming. It is doable - arguino is the best example

Comment: If you use C++ specific features like `std::cout` or `std::string`, then no, must use libc++.

Comment: I do not understand. You can't "replace C++ stdlib with C stdlib", in any way. These are different things.

Comment: On Point 2, this C++ vs. C discussion with embedded systems.  One has to write **functionally equivalent C code** to compare with C++ implementation.  That means inheritance, virtual functions, exceptions and overloading operators, specifically `operator<<` and `operator>>`.  Only then can C be compared equivalently to C++.  I've seen C language coded to use inheritance and virtual methods.  It's a lot of code and work.

Comment: At my shop, the primary reason people are not using C++, is that they don't know C++ (the obj.method() format is foreign to them).  I'm have a hard time getting them to switch to C++ just to use references and the `bool` type. :-(

Comment: Does anyone ever *really* know C++?

Comment: @jaja360: I'm curious as to how you might use, for example, `nullptr_t` or `std::initializer_list` without including a C++ header.

Comment: @NicolBolas I wouldn't. I was thinking of someone who never use any c++ library features (so, he uses only C functions), but would like to sometimes use some c++ non-library features (like namespace, static_cast, const_cast, etc.)

Comment: @jaja360: `std::nullptr_t` is the type of the language feature `nullptr`, which is the value that represents a null pointer constant. `std::initializer_list` is a library type generated *by the compiler* when you use the langauge braced-init-list in certain cases. And there are plenty of standard library features that any decent C++ program should have no problem using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to replace C++ standard library with C standard library when linking C++ programs?

No, it is not possible. Typically, C++ standard library is implemented on top of C interface. You have to link with both.

> Would it be possible to compile the program as a C++ program (using e.g., g++) but link the program with the C standard library (e.g., libc) instead of the C++ standard library (e.g., libstdc++) ?

Not "instead", but just "without" C++ standard library. Just use `gcc`.

```
gcc file.cpp
```

Basically, the difference between `g++` and `gcc`, is that `g++` links with C++ standard library. Inspect `gcc -v` vs `g++ -v` verbose output.

> target system has low memory (e.g., an embedded system) where the C++ stdlib would be too big for the available memory.

Specifically, `std::cout` (i.e. `std::ostream`) is heavy, because of buffering and whole support for `std::iomanip` stuff. And in most cases `std::cout` is not optimized for embedded (smaller size), like for example `printf` is. Exceptions are rather avoided or not used at all, because of how are they implemented - speed first, with no regard to size. In embedded, you use C++ normally. Very big MBed and Arduino are both prominent examples of C++ in bare-metal world.

> would replacing the C++ stdlib with the C stdlib solves the issue and

No, C++ stdlib and C stdlib are different things.

> allows these people to use C++ language features (namespace, more type safety, etc.) at no cost ?

It is not forbidden in any way.

> Why aren't today's C programmers doing this?

Why aren't C++ programmers writing in Rust or Java? Most probably because they like the programming language that they like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So just to be sure, it means that if I use C++ language features, but never `#include` any C++ stdlib headers, I can compile using `gcc` instead of `g++` and I will be sure that (1) the program will compile without warnings even though I use C++ features and (2) only libc will be included in my executable, correct ?

Comment: `but never #include` No, `#include` only includes a file, it's unrelated. Specifically, if you never use _symbols_ from libstdc++.so. You can declare a function anywhere, not specifically from `#include`. You can include the file, and also have template instatations, and use functions defined in header, etc. Used symbols matter. `the program will compile without warnings` well, that is unrelated to using C++, and depends on how you write the program, `only libc will be included in my executable` and also "only" crt0 and some other initialization stuff.

Comment: Basically it is sounds like a [freestanding environment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/freestanding), but that's something different, but maybe interesting for you to research. Just like "Embedded C++", `EC++`.